# firing button_click event with code and returning DialogResult.OK

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, visual-studio-2013

I would like to fire a button click event if the user presses enter on a text box but when I do the button is not returning a DialogResult.OK.  When I physically click the button it works though.  Any ideas?

Here is my parent form code

```
using (var completedForm = new CompletedForm(Qty))
{
    DialogResult result = completedForm.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return completedForm.QtyCompleted;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Qty, Please Try Again");
  return 0;  
}
```

Here is my child form button click event

```
private void btnPartialComplete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(tbQtyComplete.Text == "")
    {
        tbQtyComplete.Text = "0";
    }

    this.QtyCompleted = int.Parse(tbQtyComplete.Text);
    this.Close();
}
```

And here is my textbox keydown event

```
private void tbQtyComplete_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        btnPartialComplete_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the textbox event wouldn't cause the button to return a DialogResult.OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [btnPartialComplete.PerformClick()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx). By calling `PerformClick()` you are generating a click event for your button but when you call `btnPartialComplete_Click` you just executing a function which is registered to be executed when click event of the button is raised. So calling `btnPartialComplete_Click` is not equal to  clicking the button.